# Using 'echo' in a way that automatically fits the row width

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, echo, command-prompt

I have a need to display a list of files with full paths as just something to look at while processing. I don't like how some results are so long they continue all the way to a second line, displeasing the aesthetic. I have a way to trim the rest of the file to fit my current window:

```
if "%echo%"=="%echo:~,160%" (echo %echo%) else (echo %echo:~,160%...)
```

This will successfully trim the line, and display '...' in the end of a trimmed line to signal that the filename is cut off like so:

"d:\this is\a long\path to\a file somewhere in the tree (21-08-22) ke..."

This method has the downside of only working on a certain size window. My question is how do I make this automatic? Is there a way to detect the characters per row automatically so each line is cut the right way for everyone, for every size window?

Comment: use powershell instead. It can automatically format tables and columns like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The window width can be determined by `mode con`

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('mode con') do if "%%a"=="Columns" set "width=%%b"

set /a width-=4

set "text=123456"
call :showline

set "text=123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
call :showline
exit /b

:showline
if "!text!"=="!text:~,%width%!" (echo !text!) else (echo !text:~,%width%!...)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in batch, however, you need to check the number of columns before each output in case the console has been resized by the user.

Note, doing this for every output adds significant overhead.

```bat
@Echo off

(Set \n=^^^
%= \n newline var =%
)

%= Begin macro COUT definition    =% Set COUT=For %%n in (1 2)Do If %%n==2 (%\n%
%= Strip up to 1 leading space    =%  If "!COUT_input:~0,1!"==" " Set "COUT_input=!COUT_input:~1!"%\n%
%= Capture column value from mode =%  For /f "tokens=2 Delims=:" %%G in ('Mode Con^^^|%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /lic:"Columns:"')Do (%\n%
%= Offset column value by 3       =%   For /f %%v in ('Set/A %%G - 3')Do (%\n%
%= Compare input against len. cap =%    If "!COUT_input:~,%%v!"=="!COUT_input!" (%\n%
%= Display input if LSS cap       =%     Echo(!COUT_input:~0,%%v!%\n%
%= Display input... if GTR Cap    =%    ) Else Echo(!COUT_input:~0,%%v!...%\n%
                                      ))%\n%
%= End the macro environment      =%  Endlocal%\n%
%= Enable macro env + Capt. input =% ) Else Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion ^& Set COUT_input=

:Demo
 mode 30,30
 %COUT% %computername%;%TEMP%;%__APPDIR__%
 Pause
 mode 160,30
 %COUT% %computername%;%TEMP%;%__APPDIR__%
 TImeout /t 3 /Nobreak
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell provides the console width in the $Host variable.

```
$TEXT='01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789'
$TextLength = $TEXT.Length
$ScreenWidth = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width - 3
if ($TextLength -gt $ScreenWidth) {
    $OutText = $TEXT.Substring(0, [Math]::min($TEXT.Length, $ScreenWidth)) + '...'
} else {
    $OutText = $TEXT
}
Write-Host $OutText
```

If you must run this from a `cmd.exe` shell, the following might be used.

```
SET "TEXT=01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789"
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "$TextLength = '%TEXT%'.Length;" ^
    "$ScreenWidth = $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Width - 3;" ^
    "if ($TextLength -gt $ScreenWidth) {" ^
        "$OutText = '%TEXT%'.Substring(0, [Math]::min('%TEXT%'.Length, $ScreenWidth)) + '...'" ^
    "} else {" ^
        "$OutText = '%TEXT%'" ^
    "}" ^
    "Write-Host $OutText"
```